# How do I repair my window and stop water coming in

Tags: windows

[image]We have a fixed pane window that is wood in the inside but seems to be vinyl on the outside.

[image]
Inside the house there is a removable pane, then it's a fixed exterior pane.

I noticed a damp patch appearing, so I put silicone on the exterior windows between the glass and the vinyl, 
[image]

this doesn't seem to have fixed the issue and the damp patch was spreading, so I removed the wood
[image]

There was a lot of wet decaying wood.

I noticed there is a little plastic tube that isn't quite aligned with the weep hole, can this cause the issue?

I think I can just fill the hole with epoxy or plastic wood, but
 1. Do I need to do anything with the small plastic tube drain, that is near the weep hole?
 2. There seems to be caulk/silicone inside the rotted space that is coming off, can I just caulk outside the window? Or should I try to seal it from the inside? I can only seal up to where I have removed the wood

3. Any other tips?

[image]

Comment: What kind of exterior siding do you have? Sill seems picthed water should drain leak may be up higher.

Comment: if one window like that rest will do the same.

Comment: Do not seal weep holes ,water will pool and wreck even more,

Comment: Added bigger picture, note that the gutters have gutter guards and are clear inside,I need to move the debis but there are plenty of gaps for water to run into

Comment: Ya gutter dirty. Look at roof  flashing above window near house or  crack in roof capping.  Hard to say looks ok. Roof not flat is it. Has to be up high and runs down. my guess.

Comment: Roof is not flat. Have contractor coming tomorrow to check out. Will let you know what he says

Comment: Would like that.

Comment: Contractor thinks that water must be running down the side of the window, going to seal the whole frame with QuadMax and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes could be ,good luck

Comment: I realize my comment is late, but I suspect your windows may be Pella, although I cannot see any indicator markings on the glass. My monitor does not show the weep holes, but they should be on either side of glass, in lower corners. Were they regularly cleaned out? Were the wood pieces between the panes of glass regularly sealed with Spar or similar? Your chimney showed signs of mortar failure which needs attention, very soon.  Is it possible that the chimney flashing also needs replaced and is further contributing to water runoff? The gutter debris may further add to the water runoff.